# Problem with resolving relative paths in non-main package

Tags: go, relative-path

I'm having trouble resolving relative file paths in my Go application. For this app I decided to make a package that offers a uniform interface to the different configuration files. The `conf` package contains the relevant data files, so this is basically the file tree:

```
app/conf
    + config.go
    + config.json
    + ...
app/code
    + code.go
    + code_test.go
```

Problem is, when the tests defined in `app/code/code_test.go` calls a function in the `app/conf` package, which in turn tries to open `app/conf/config.json`, the relative path is messed up since the working directory is at `app/code`.

- I've looked at other SO answers that mentions the `path/filepath` package and especially the `filepath.Abs` [function](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Abs) for turning relative paths to absolute paths. However, this won't solve my problem since the absolute path will be based on the *wrong working directory.*
- Some solution with *"absolute paths"* based on GOPATH would probably suffice, but I imagine the GOPATH would have little meaning when the code is built and exported.
- Simply porting all configuration files to hard coded Go structs is not viable either as they're used cross-language.

Comment: Do you have this problem only in your test files? I'm asking because they aren't included in the final build. So after you build and deploy your app, there will be no `code_test.go` to exec a func in `app/conf`...

Comment: @mkopriva no sorry I was unclear, the functions are called from the actual imlementation files (`code.go` in the above example) but the functions would be invoked from the actual `main` package as well, i.e. not only in testing.

Comment: Then you could instruct your users to install the config files in a known location, whether absolute, or relative to the binary is a decision for you to make. Alternatively you could instruct your users to provide the location of the configs, either as a cli arg, or an env var, or both.

Comment: ... a 3rd alternative would be to "embed" the configs into the final binary. This is not supported out of the box by the go command but there are 3rd party libraries that can do that for you.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I was thinking about such a solution; e.g. instructing users to define some enviromental variable or the like, but I was wondering if there's a better and conventional solution that is a little more "native" to Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on a config file path within your source is not only an issue in unit tests, but it will also be an issue in production. Typically, code would do something like this:

- The config handler accepts an `io.Reader` which it will read configuration from.
- `main` will open a file (whose path might be hard-coded, passed by command line, passed by env var, etc) and pass it to the config handler for reading.
- Unit tests of the config handler will instead hard-code a config (or multiple configs, to test different scenarios) into something like `bytes.Buffer` and pass that to the config handler to read instead.
- Unit tests of anything other than the code which reads the config file (so, anything that *uses* the configuration but does not *manipulate* it), would generate the `Config` struct in code rather than reading it from a real *or* fake file, as part of the test harness. For example, `myConf := config.Config{SomeProp: "foo", OtherProp: true}` and then pass that to the function under test.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, **very good answer**. I was looking for a way to base my tests on the config dynamically, rather than explicitly testing against static config values in the tests because much of the config will remain constant anyway. But I guess the motive behind this was convenience more than anything else.

Comment: There's no reason you can't define a struct literal and re-use it in multiple tests (even across multiple packages), for convenience.

Comment: Some **behavioral tests** rely on highly personalized ICC profiles that is part of the config and are adapted for the system running the tests. Thus, these profiles can't be hard coded, lest the test suite becomes extremely flaky. So while I think I've found a way to model parts of the system to your suggestions, I have a hard time seeing how I could avoid a dynamic configuration during testing of those components.

Comment: Without knowing more, all I could suggest is to refactor your code to be less environment-specific (i.e. so that tests don't need to rely on the profile of the system on which it is running). Unit tests should be 100% reproducible on any system with no system-specific changes.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help anyway. Those components perform image recognition on-screen and are in need of some basic testing, but those tests aren't and will never be proper unit tests.